# href links not clickable on iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone

There are two links in one of my websites that are not clickable on iphone. They work fine on ipad but not on iphone.
I have already searched but I cannot find a solution.

The HTML is like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <ul class="logo_links"> 
      <li style="margin-bottom: -6px; margin-top:1px;"><a class="navLinks" href="http://deals.city.domain.com/">DEALS</a></li> 
      <li><a class="navLinks" href="http://connectsoon.domain.gr/">CONNECT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a [link](http://alexandroupoli.topgreekgyms.gr) to the website. The problem is with the links next to the logo/name 'DEALS' and 'CONNECT' that show at the left of the navigation.

What is the solution?
Thank u in advance for any help!

Comment: I didn't think I'd ever say this on SO, but the now a link to the site in question would actually be nice for someone to confirm this.

Comment: Oh! I thought I added it! Sorry, crazy day!

Comment: Day 2: Your website is still loading :) It isn't responsive so maybe the problem isn't only in mobiles. What are the links that don't work?

Comment: It is responsive I am able to see it from my ipad and iphone. The links are the ones next to the logo. 'DEALS' and 'CONNECT'